# Decimal Format conversion issue

Tags: java, android, decimalformat

I'm using DecimalFormat in order to convert double to string like this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.###");

df.format(km);
```

The problem is, although the variable km has the value of `9.655195710258606E-5`, the result of the df.format method returns `0` as string.But I expect something like `9.655` instead of `0`.

Any help & suggestions will be appreciated

Thank you for your concern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as it should. The string "9.655" would be wrong. The value is actually 0.00009655 and if you round it to 3 decimal places you get "0".

To see some more digits, you can use more decimal places in the format `#.######` or force scientific notation with a format like this `#.###E0`.

Comment: What should I do in order to not get "0" ? Should I change the "###.###" pattern in constructor not to get "0" ?

Answer (score 0):

In the end of these numbers, the E(x) represents the exponent. E-5, means the exponent is -5, which means the actual number is 9.655 * (1/(10^5)).